# How to add static resources to vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I am running a vaadin application and have some css files that reference images using "url()" syntax.

The images however are not available and on the server side you get the error:

```
rejecting published file request for file that has not been published
```

I have tried putting them nearly everywhere (WEB-INF, WEB-INF/classes, VAADIN, VAADIN/themes/.., etc) but they remain unaccessible.

How can I add static images to my vaadin application so they can be accessed by css?

**UPDATE**

Note that the images need to be accessible by css in the form of:

```
.myCssClass {
    background: url(path/to/image.png);
}
```

Comment: your class is within the theme?  then under your (working) theme dir in VAADIN/themes/daTheme/path/to/image.png should work.  see e.g. https://github.com/m00g33k/vaadin-dashboard-demo/tree/master/VaadinDashboard/WebContent/VAADIN/themes/dashboard which has icon fonts and images referenced.

Comment: **UPDATE** Some major changes on this topic with Vaadin 10 Flow. See this 2018-07 Vaadin.com blog post by Leif Åstrand, [*Vaadin 10 and static resources*](https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-10-and-static-resources) for some great explanation of the old way and new way of placing static resources, and how the Servlet 2 and Servlet 3 specs relate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put them to `VAADIN/themes/mytheme/images/` and set the theme name to `mytheme`. They way how you set theme depends on your Vaadin version.
Resources will be accessible like that:

```java
new ThemeResource("images/my_image.png");
```

Comment: This does not help me if I want to access them from css

Comment: then you need to place your css under `VAADIN/themes/mytheme/css/` and use like that `images/my_image.png`

Comment: **UPDATE** Some major changes on this topic with Vaadin 10 Flow. See this 2018-07 Vaadin.com blog post by Leif Åstrand, [*Vaadin 10 and static resources*](https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-10-and-static-resources) for some great explanation of the old way and new way of placing static resources, and how the Servlet 2 and Servlet 3 specs relate.