# Spring boot vaadin static content

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, vaadin7, vaadin4spring

I'm using spring boot with vaadin. How should I serve VAADIN folder? I deploy to production using gradle distZip task, which creates a lib and a bin folder. I don't want to include VAADIN folder into the jar because it disables caching and makes a fat jar.

Where should I place the folder, what modifications must be done to serve it from a directory, and not the jar itself?

Comment: Similar Question: [*How to add static resources to vaadin*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24364251/642706)

Comment: **UPDATE** Some major changes on this topic with [Vaadin 10 Flow](https://vaadin.com/flow). See this 2018-07 Vaadin.com blog post by Leif Åstrand, [*Vaadin 10 and static resources*](https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-10-and-static-resources) for some great explanation of the old way and new way of placing static resources, and how the *Servlet 2* and *Servlet 3* specs relate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serve static resources from a Vaadin/Spring application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292439/how-to-serve-static-resources-from-a-vaadin-spring-application)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this fits your needs but your resources can be outsourced to a [CDN provider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) or to your own server or servlet that is better optimized to serve static content.

```
@WebServlet( value = "/*",  initParams = @WebInitParam( name = "Resources", 
                 value = "http://your-cdn.provider.com/cdn-example" ) )
```

See [this article](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/optimizing-hosting-setup) for further details.